# SSO for Bugzilla using Keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, bugzilla

I've been working on this project a while now and web search has not returned anything useful other than advertisements for services. I want to use Keycloak to authenticate a local Bugzilla installation. I've been able to set up LDAP for authentication to the Bugzilla site but trying to get SAML or OAuth, OpenID, etc... is almost impossible.

It's difficult to find information on the web if you don't know what keywords to search for and only advertisements are returned that have nothing to do with my query. I'm probably posting this in the wrong place on the web so I would appreciate some kind of clue that will direct me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: No specific problem. Quick google search and you will get Bugzilla OIDC auth plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I found this: but it says it's not being maintained. https://github.com/jalcine/bugzilla-openid

Comment: which one did you find Jan? Did it work? I couldnt get the one by jalcine to install or work. I guess it's not maintained any longer.